# Query Builder acts like eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I just want to know, can I create 'eloquent relationship' using query builder on Laravel. Is there a way to do that?

**Example:**

I have two table

```
users
========
user_id
user_name

events
========
event_id
event_name
user_id
```

I know that if I want to select event and want to show the user who create the event I can do it like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model
{
    public function events() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Event::class, 'user_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

In Controller I can just call it like this

```
User::find(1)->with('events');
```

But In this case I have a complex query and join 3 table, I'm afraid about the complexity so I want to make it only using query builder not eloquent but is there a way to make it like the eloquent behaviour?

Expectation: (I know its a wrong query but is there a way to make it ?)

```
DB::select('select * from users where user_id = ?', [1])->with('events');
```

**Example Expected Result:**

```
user: {
    user_id: 1,
    user_name: 'Mr. Man',
    events: [
        {
            event_id: 1,
            event_name: 'Birthday Party'
        },
        {
            event_id: 2,
            event_name: 'Honey Moon'
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit:

I think I must too make it clear like my case, this is what I expected

I have three table

```
users
=====
user_id

events
======
event_id
user_id
event_location
event_date

event_organizers
================
event_organizer_id
event_organizer_name

package_event_organizers
========================
package_event_organizer_id
event_organizer_id
package_event_organizer_name
```

My expectation

```
events: [
    {
        event_organizer_id: 1,
        event_organizer_name: 'Wedding',
        event_location: 'New York',
        event_date: '2021/09/12',
        package_event_organizers: [
            {
                package_event_organizer_id: 1,
                package_event_organizer_id: 'Wedding Package 1',
            },
            {
                package_event_organizer_id: 2,
                package_event_organizer_id: 'Wedding Package 2',
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        event_organizer_id: 1,
        event_organizer_name: 'Wedding',
        event_location: 'San Fransisco',
        event_date: '2021/10/12',
        package_event_organizers: [
            {
                package_event_organizer_id: 1,
                package_event_organizer_id: 'Wedding Package 1',
            },
            {
                package_event_organizer_id: 2,
                package_event_organizer_id: 'Wedding Package 2',
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        event_organizer_id: 2,
        event_organizer_name: 'Sweet 17',
        event_location: 'Chicago',
        event_date: '2021/11/12',
        package_event_organizers: [
            {
                package_event_organizer_id: 1,
                package_event_organizer_id: 'Sweet 17 Package 1',
            },
            {
                package_event_organizer_id: 2,
                package_event_organizer_id: 'Sweet 17 Package 2',
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: No you can't do this. Also why would you want to do this? The use case here is unclear.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the attention. I want to do this because I want to return a collection of data that I need to join 3 table, after that for each object will have collection of data too

Comment: Yes I don't understand why not use eloquent instead of joins

Comment: For now, I still use eloquent but I just wondering can I make query builder act like eloquent. I have read from some resource It said that too many relationship using eloquent can increase the complexity

Comment: That's too broad a statement to actually be meaningful. 3 joins is usually slower than doing `with` on 3 different relationships because of all the redundant data you get from a join so whether it's slower or not really depends on the use case.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the insight :D. I'm still new to this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible,the relations you make are functions belonging to the model it self.when you use DB an instance of laravel collection will be returned and this collection doesn't have a function called events

Answer (score 0):

When using eloquent, every fetched record instantiates a Model, therefore you can use eager load for the relationships.

When you write your query using Query Builder, you are in fact writing a raw query with no models instantiated.

The only way to retrieve relationships with query builder is by doing it manually using native DB joins or looping over each record and building a collection with the fetched Models.

```
$raw_users = DB::select('select * from users where user_id = ?', [1]);

$users = collect();
foreach ($raw_users as $user) {
    $users->add(User::find($user->user_id)->with('events'));
}

return $users;
```

If you don't face any performance issues, I would recommend you to use eloquent because of simplicity, otherwise, just write your own raw query.

Doing what I wrote above works, but is just a waste of resources.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, do you think it is better for me do like yours or using eloquent instead (There are 3 table to join and return a collection of table)

Comment: It depends on your query performance. As per my experience, if you are doing just 3 simple joins and you are working on tables with few records, go ahead with eloquent and avoid a headache. If you need to join some tables with millions of records, you may face performance issues and memory peaks if your indexes are not well declared. In that case, write a raw query.